# Write method inside getView

Tags: java, android, adapter, getview

I am trying to write a method inside `getView()` in a `listview` adapter as below

```
public class CardsDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {
    public CardsDataAdapter(Context context) {super(context, R.layout.view);}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, final View contentView, ViewGroup parent){
       TextView text = (TextView)(contentView.findViewById(R.id.content));
       text.setText(getItem(position));

    //This is the method I want to trigger, but says it's not allowed to write here
     public static void triggerThis(){
    dothisthing.method(getItem(position))
    }

return contentView;}
```

I need a static method because I want to call it in another class. I have searched everywhere to find other solutions to trigger that kind of action but no success.

Answer (score 1):

```
   @Override
 public View getView(int position, final View contentView, ViewGroup parent){
   TextView text = (TextView)(contentView.findViewById(R.id.content));
   text.setText(getItem(position));

    triggerThis();
 return contentView;}

 public static void triggerThis(){
     dothisthing.method(getItem(position))
    }
```

Comment: which part of "I want to call it in another class" did not understand? and getItem(position) is not recognized outside getview

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call a function this way  `public static void triggerThis()` to call the function you just use the function or method name. e.g.  `triggerThis()`